# how to get week between to given dates?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have two fields `Starting date` and `End date` I want to get the week between them with one decimal point that is the extra day if any. suppose `10` days will be soon as `1.3` and `24 as 3.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code below.

```
Date startDate = Date.newInstance(2016, 6, 16);
Date endDate = Date.newInstance(2016, 7, 13);
Integer noOfDays = startDate.daysBetween(endDate);
Integer wholeWeeks = Math.floor(noOfDays / 7).intValue();
Integer daysLeft = noOfDays-(wholeWeeks*7);
System.debug('Days Between = '+noOfDays);
String strWeeksBetwwn = wholeWeeks+'.'+daysLeft; 
Decimal decWeeksBetwwn = decimal.valueOf(strWeeksBetwwn);
System.debug('Weeks Between = '+ decWeeksBetwwn);
```

Output:

```
USER_DEBUG [6]|DEBUG|Days Between = 27
17:27:09:004 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|Weeks Between = 3.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Date startDate = Date.newInstance(2016, 8, 16);
Date endDate = Date.newInstance(2016, 8, 26);
Decimal daysBetween = startDate.daysBetween(endDate);

System.debug('Days Between = '+daysBetween);
System.debug('Weeks Between = '+ (daysBetween/7).setScale(1));
```

Comment: Can you check your answer, for dates `2016, 6, 16` and `2016, 7, 13`. It is coming 3.9.